# Mirroring PNG Images set transparent to black - Any Solution?

Tags: c#, image-processing

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PbImame.Image);

bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);

//Show them in a picturebox

PbImageMirrored.Image = bmp;

Or

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PbImame.Image);

// public Mirror(bool mirrorX, bool mirrorY)

Accord.Imaging.Filters.Mirror filter = new  Accord.Imaging.Filters.Mirror(false, true);

filter.ApplyInPlace(mirror);

PbImageMirrored.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: You forgot to add a language tag. Is it C# ?

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Click `edit` under your question, select the code with your mouse and click `{}` beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format as code. What is your question please?

Comment: How to mirror a PNG image without the transparent parts changing to black as if using the methods already mentioned?

Comment: I have used the PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb and has been resolved. Thanks.